# Rational Limits for Non-rational roots

Tags: number-theory, limits

I discovered the following relationship while playing around with concepts discussed in recent Veritasium [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovJcsL7vyrk).

Let's consider the sequence 
$$
_{+1}=(−1) _{}+_{+1}
$$
$$
_{+1}=_{}+_{}
$$
where x is any positive integer and $a_{0}$ and $b_{0}$ can be any real numbers

Now any idea or guidance on how to prove the following result?:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{_{+1}}{_{}} =  \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_{+1}}{b_{}}  =1 + \sqrt{x}$$ 
$$AND$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{_{}}{b_{}} = \sqrt{x}
$$

Comment: What has your question to do with `number-theory`? Or with `elementary-number-theory`?

Comment: Updated with "Limits" but "Number Theory" was shown as top recommendation so I kept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more precise about the statement of your claim: e.g., if $a_0=b_0=0$, none of the limits you want to study exists. In what follows I will explain how to prove the result you want *provided those limits exist*. moreover, I'll suppose that $b_n\neq 0\neq a_n$ for every $n$.

Observe that the conditions above can be rewritten as $$a_{n+1}=xb_n+a_n, \quad b_{n+1}=a_n+b_n.$$
We put $c_n:=a_n/b_n$. Then, from the equations above we have $$a_{n+1}/a_n=x/c_n +1, \quad b_{n+1}/b_n=c_n+1.$$
Dividing the first by the second, we get $$c_{n+1}/c_n=(x/c_n+1)/(c_n+1),$$
from which we get $c_{n+1}=(x+c_n)/(c_n+1)$. 
Now, suppose that the limit of the sequence $c_n$ exists, and call it $L$. Then, it must satisfy the equation $L=\frac{x+L}{L+1}$, from which we get $L^2=x$, which is the second limit you want to get. The first one follows easily from this result and the equations above.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction.